# Replacing object file during compilation by cmake

Tags: c++, cmake

first the question:
How to replace object files after compilation, but before creation of static library ?

Now the explanation.

Let's say that I have a two projects which compile the same object file, with the same name, but one of the objects include so additional (fake)functionality for testing purpose:

```
Proj_A
     compile -> A_OBJECT.o (fake functionality)
Proj_B
     compile -> A_OBJECT.o (original)
```

During the compilation first Proj_A is compiled and at the end Proj_B.

Now, I would like to copy/replace file from Proj_A to Proj_B to build static library which will be used to test 'fake' functionality.

I try to different commands like *file(), configure_file(), add_custom_command()*, but without success.

Thank you for any help/hint in advanced !

Best,
Martin

Comment: file(), configure_file() will be executed at configuration time, so will not work. Can you show an example of what you tried with add_custom_command() ? It could probably acieve what you want with the right arguments

Comment: add_custom_command(TARGET Proj_B 
        PRE_LINK 
        WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/Proj_A/CMakeFiles/Proj_A.dir/source/ 
        COMMAND cp A_OBJECT.cpp.o "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/Proj_B/CMakeFiles/Proj_B.dir/source"
    )

Comment: Hi, you could probably use the generator expression, $<TARGET_OBJECTS:ProjectA> and declare Project B with add_library(ProjectB ${SOURCES} $<TARGET_OBJECTS:ProjectA>)
https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html

You'll need to declare project A as an Object library.